# Is there any way to make dialog's header and footer sticky in angular material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, dialog

When I scroll the content of [Dialog](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-modal-popup-example/#.Xy04eygzbIX), right top `close` and right bottom `Ok` button also getting scrolled.

I want to make those `button` fixed, not to scrolled so that any time I can `close` the dialog.

This my code

```
<div md-dialog-content>
     <button class="close" mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">
        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
     </button>

//here my table content
    
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button id="matbuttonClosedownSide" color="primary" mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="null">Ok</button>
</div>
```

code to open model

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(myModalComponent, {
width: '80%',
height:'80%',
panelClass: 'my-dialog',
disableClose: true ,
data:this.data[index]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I did it like follows:

```
.my-dialog {
  .mat-dialog-container {
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 50px; // height of  your sticky footer
  }

  .sticky-modal-footer {
    position: absolute;

    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;

    border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
    background-color: white;

    padding: 10px 24px;
  }
}
```

And then added the dialog buttons in a footer element:

```
<button class="close" matDialogClose>
  <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
</button>
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{ modalTitle }}</h1>
<hr />
<mat-dialog-content> Dialog content </mat-dialog-content>
<footer class="sticky-modal-footer">
  <button color="primary">OK</button>
</footer>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't seems work for me

Comment: nested css doesnt work for me.. is there another way?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem yesteday. After some research I found the `mat-dialog-title` and `mat-dialog-actions` [directives](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#directives). That did the trick for me:

```
<h3 mat-dialog-title>This is the sticky header</h3>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="start">
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Accept</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

You may need to fill the the `<mat-dialog-content></mat-dialog-content>` with more text to see the scrollbar. But it shows the basic idea: the header stays sticky above the scrollable content and the buttons stay sticky at the bottom.

My sample code is strongly inspired by this official Angular Material Dialog example: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples#dialog-content